# Android Is it possible to have multiple nav_graph files?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

So I was using `Jetpack navigation` and the number of fragments kept growing up.

We can **separate fragments in different navigation graph** as described in this document

[jetpack nav graph docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs)

Then I tried to put different nav graphs in different files because that felt more organized and readable file but I get the following error when I try to navigate to different nav_graph files.

nav_graph_start.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_start"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashScreen"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
        android:name="com.timetoface.android.splash.SplashFragment"
        android:label="Login Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splash_to_login"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_auth"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splash_to_home"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_home"
            />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

nav_graph_auth.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_auth"
    app:startDestination="@id/emailLoginScreen"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">
................................
</navigation>
```

nav_graph_home.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/emailLoginScreen"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">
................................
</navigation>
```

> navigation destination com.app.android:id/nav_graph_home
>   referenced from action com.app.android:id/action_splash_to_home
>   is unknown to this NavController

So,

Are m**ultiple navigation graph files not supported** yet?

Am I missing something that I should change?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you can use include. Take a look **[this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs)**

example: first_graph.xml

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/second_graph" />
```

then set action to included graph's id

```
 <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_to_second_graph"
        app:destination="@id/second_graph" />
```

Also you can use extension to use multiple graphs merged.

Take a look to **[this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)**

Actually every activity should have it's own nav graph.

Comment: @NarekHayrapetyan what are you referring to in that example in regards to the extension to use multiple graphs merged

Comment: @w3bshark You can find more details here

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can have multiple nav graph in your application. Each Activity can have only one Navigation Graph. I just added two Nav_Graph for different activity. Works fine. Here is a screenshot of my Navigation folder.

[image]