# How to navigate to a specific fragment from another nav_graph without a "global action"?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have two navigation graphs:

- nav_one

  - frag A: **start destination**
  - frag B

    - connection through frag A
  - frag C

    - connection through frag B
- nav_two

  - frag X: **start destination**
  - frag Y

    - connection through frag X
  - frag Z

    - connection through frag C

How can one navigate from a fragment from `nav_one` to a specific fragment from `nav_two` without a "global action"?

Example: I want to navigate from frag B to frag Z.

---

I'd like to highlight that this question **does not** have any relation to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403519/android-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-nav-graph-files)

---

Comment: I don't think you can navigate to a fragment from a sub graph at all, except the start destination. When navigating the navigation component will only look for immediate entries in the graph, not nested ones, so you'll get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, there is no way to do such a thing with navigation actions. You can only navigate directly to it's start destination.

For more information about, the Android team has just released a video that answers that question. Check out 1:25

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvFSJVTGDb4

Comment: Is there still no way around this issue in 2024?

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to create a deep link, and it works as intended. However, this method recreates the MainActivity, so I briefly see the SplashScreen.

```
            NavDeepLinkBuilder(it)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.your_nav_two)
                .setDestination(R.id.your_frag_Z_id)
                .setArguments(some args) - if you need it
                .createPendingIntent().send()
```

[https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#:~:text=to%20the%20stack.-,This%20means%20that%20when%20a%20user%20presses%20the%20Back%20button,implicit%20deep%20link%20was%20triggered](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#:%7E:text=to%20the%20stack.-,This%20means%20that%20when%20a%20user%20presses%20the%20Back%20button,implicit%20deep%20link%20was%20triggered).

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this help you

Sub graphs

[image: Sub graphs]